# how to make a chart (time vs memory) in excel?

Tags: excel, charts

I have data like below:
[my data and chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6WDc.jpg)

But, I want a chart (time vs memory) similar below:

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLs4r.jpg)

How to make it?

Comment: You could very well do this in excel. What is your question? Please add more details to the question

Comment: I want to create a chart which vertical axis: are values of times (seconds), horizontal category: are values of memory (KB)

Comment: What have you tried? Can you see the big chart button in excel? try clicking it

Comment: Please see my chart I try on the top ( my chart and data)

Answer (score 0):

Your excel data looks good. But looks like you have selected line chart to perform this. You must be using scatter chart for plotting X and Y axis multiple series. Please follow the below steps,

- Select time and memory data for 'A' alone, (B2:C4)
- Select scatter chart which shows scatter with lines. Now you have 'A' series ready in the graph. You can add series name also.
- Right click on chart and select 'Select data'.
- In 'Legend entries' click add and select the series name, X and Y axis range. X values should be time and Y should be memory or vice versa based on your requirement.
- Do the same for 'C' as well and you have got what you wanted

Let me know if you need any help